# Can't build Autocomplete textbox in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I've been trying to learn how to build an autocomplete textbox that fetches the cities from my database, I use XAMPP so it's mySQL. Following is the code that I picked up from a tutorial and modified according to my needs:

demo.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Autocomplete demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>   

</head>

<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="city">Region: </label>
    <input id="city">
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'sample_master';

    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['city'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    //"region" is the column from the table I wish to fetch
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE region LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY region");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['region'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

In xampp I startup the MySQL and Apache server, and then open demo.html from htdocs. The autocomplete feature doesn't work(nothing shows up while I'm typing). What am I doing wrong? Also, the cities DB has excess of 3,00,000 records.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Inspect the network traffic in your browser inspector. Is the XHR request firing to search.php and what is the response?

Comment: @AronCederholm It does fire queries to search.php when I type, but they show cancelled status.

Answer (score 2):

autocomplete default $_GET is $_GET['term'] ,you are called $_GET['city'] so you need to change your $_GET name or you can define your GET name like below..

```
$(function() {
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(r,res){
        $.get('search.php',{city:r.term},res,'json');//r is input typing request,res is response result as json
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It does seem to work internally, I checked the XHR and it gave a 200 OK status(Before it returned "Cancelled" status). But nothing shows up on the textbox. I added the above code and kept the $_GET ['city'], tried changing it to $_GET['term'] without any changes within the HTML function call as well. No results.